# Right click and middle button click swaped

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the right click is not working in the right way. If I tap with two fingers on the touchpad the system reads a middle button click. But if I tap with 3 fingers the right click works. This is just too wrong for me, and every solution I've tried don't work.

Comment: did you install gnome-tweaks? If not, you can install and configure touchpad from there.

Comment: Gnome-tweaks is already installed. It didin't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this, then configure from gnome-tweaks

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```

Comment: This not work. Do I have to reboot to apply?

Comment: Yes, try rebooting. It should work, if not then there's a problem in installation. I suggest reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: So I'll have to reinstall. I'll be back to tell if this will work.

Comment: Reinstall?? No way.

Comment: Well... Reinstall works fine. I don't know what happened but now it's all fine.